# How should I fix a missing p2 directory in my Eclipse install?

Tags: installation, eclipse

Recently rebuilt my PC and have a new Java Eclipse install.  I did it a bit differently to what it was before and used the Installer, then I installed the Installer as well to help manage updates, etc.  Seemed like a good idea.

When I start Eclipse it throws some errors.  The main problem right now is that my Eclipse install directory does not have a p2 directory.  There is a p2 directory in the Installer directory and under my User directory, but Eclipse is looking for it in the main install directory.  It gives this error:

`Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\Java\Eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry`

For reference, the Installer directory is `C:\Program Files\Java\Eclipse\eclipse-installer` and as mentioned, there is a p2 directory in here with the necessary files.  The main installation lives under `c:\Program Files\Java\Eclipse\java-2021-03`.

I'm not sure how I ended up in this situation when I basically just followed the instructions in the installation wizard.  Do I need to reinstall or is there a way to fix the install in a way that will be permanent (ie. not a workaround)?  If I need to reinstall, should I put the Installer in the same directory as the Eclipse install itself, or is there something else I should have done differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more reading and searching online and decided to just reinstall Eclipse, but this time without using the installer - turns out the zip file comes with a p2 directory inside it where it belongs!  Looks like the installer did a bad install for me, so I won't bother with it next time.

Side note: I also learned there is no uninstaller for Eclipse, which meant all I needed to do was delete the old directory, BUT contrary to popular belief it **does** actually put entries in the registry and there is no way to remove them except manually if you really want them gone.